# Calculating total orders per day, value per day with timezone awareness

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Everything in the database is stored in UTC (datetime)

We have people who are in different time-zones and we want to generate a graph for them in their local time.

The stored data consists of

```
Id
TimeOfOrder
ValueOfOrder
```

Given two dates into a stored procedure I want to output

```
Date          OrderCount          OrderValue
2016-01-01    10                  30000
```

So the OrderCount is a COUNT of all the rows in that date
OrderValue is a SUM(ValueOfOrder)

This part I managed to do quite quickly using a CTE

```
declare @dtStartDate datetime 
set @dtStartDate='2016-01-01'
declare @dtEndDate datetime 
set @dtEndDate ='2016-01-31'

;WITH DateSequence([PlotPointDate]) AS 
    (
        SELECT @dtStartDate AS [PlotPointDate]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [PlotPointDate])
        FROM DateSequence
        WHERE [PlotPointDate] < @dtEndDate
    )
    SELECT CAST(@dtStartDate AS Date), COUNT(1), SUM(ValueOfOrder) WHERE TimeOfOrder > [PlotPointDate] And TimeOfOrder < DATEADD(d,1,[PlotPointDate])
```

Simple enough so far, however if I now want to get the data in non UTC (any other timezone) it becomes a little bit more tricky since the dates don't nicely align up.

Any suggestions to make this timezone aware?

Comment: you should apply the timezone offset to the parameters you're using `(@dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)` before calling your proc/function, unless it's stored in the database, then just pass the key you need to retrieve the offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to do it correctly in general case if you want to generate historical  reports. The offset from UTC changes in summer/winter, but the rules for daylight savings time has changed historically.

There are states/regions/countries that introduced daylight savings, then abandoned it, then brought it back. To do it properly you need a historical database that would convert UTC to a given timezone for the past years. For example, [Perth](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/perth) observed time changes in 1991 and 1992, then from 2006 to 2009. Since then their time offset remains UTC+8 all year round.

In [Moscow](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow) there were daylight saving changes till 2011, then no changes, then one change in 2014 and no changes since.

Having said all this, in SQL Server 2016 there is a new [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/mt612795.aspx) clause that may help in converting timestamps between time zones.

In practice I store the timestamp in both local and UTC time zones. When the data event is generated it is usually easy to convert local time into UTC, so I do it and store both. Some reports need local time, some UTC. It becomes much more difficult to do this conversion later for historical data.

This approach would become impractical if you need to support a lot of time zones, but it could be OK, if you know that your users are in a few well-defined time zones.

Comment: For an application either you need to have the pain of storing datetime and time zone, or just utc datetime and pass an offset when querying. You can pass the current offset at query time. Ok there are instances when the offset varies but in a historical report are users going to be that sensitive?

Comment: @Mike, of course it depends. If a simple static offset from UTC is good enough for a particular task - great. Especially if the data is generated (mostly) during the user's day time, not at night. In this case nobody would notice if data points are shifted by +-1 hour. My point was that it is hard to do it correctly in general case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass a parameter which is the timezone offset. Suggest minutes, since Some countries are 5.5 hours out. Just add the offset minutes to your CTE

Comment: The problem is that offset from UTC **usually** changes in winter/summer. The even bigger problem is that this offset may be different in different years, depending on the time zone (region).